# resource type for PNG resource in MFC

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am trying to use program resource in my `CHTMLView`using [res:protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740(v=VS.85).aspx). If I use bitmap resource type it works correct for `res://mydll.dll/#2/#234`. Here #2 is [resource type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009(v=vs.85).aspx) and #234 is resouce id. I want to use same for PNG resource. I have tried all [resource type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009(v=vs.85).aspx) and `WinUser.h` but did not find suitable match for PNG resource type. So I am not sure which resource type we should use for PNG or res:protocol does support  PNG or not. Any hint on this ?

Comment: Skip the `CHTMLView` control. Use `CImage::Load` to load the PNG, and then display it like you would any other image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no pre-defined resource type for PNG images. You should therefore use the `RT_RCDATA` type, which is for application defined data.

Comment: I tried RT_RCDATA  (i.e. #10 ) but no luck , not sure if I am missing anything.

Comment: There's really no other choice for resource type. Perhaps the real issue is that the `CHTMLView` control doesn't support what you are trying to do.,

Comment: @void: Did you make sure the PNG resource itself is actually stored using `RCDATA` for its type? It is not enough to just change the `res:` URL, it needs to match the actual resource. As the `res:` documentation says, you can use any valid resource type, even custom types. For example, if you store the actual resource as a `PNG` custom type, you could then use `res://mydll.dll/PNG/#234`.  How are you adding the resource to your DLL? Are you using an `.rc` file?  If so, what does it actually look like?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes, I stored resource as PNG custom type. res://mydll.dll/PNG/#234 worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps anyone. I was trying to find out how to enumerate all PNG resources in a resource file. RT_IMAGE is "2" but it didn't work. Neither did RT_RCDATA. So I called EnumResourceTypes and found a type of "PNG". I have found that if you call EnumResourceNames and pass in "PNG" you can enumerate all the PNG resources in a win32 resource file.